# Level surfaces of $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}+\ln(4-x^2-y^{2}-z^{2})$ and $g(x,y,z)=\sqrt{4-x^{2}}+\sqrt{9-y^{2}}+\sqrt{1-z^{2}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to describe the level surfaces of the functions
$$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}+\ln(4-x^2-y^{2}-z^{2})$$
and
$$g(x,y,z)=\sqrt{4-x^{2}}+\sqrt{9-y^{2}}+\sqrt{1-z^{2}}$$
For $f=k$, I get
$$\ln(4-x^2-y^2-z^2)=k-(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z})$$
and then
$$4-x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}=\exp(k-(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}))$$
I'd say it's a sphere but I believe I'm wrong. And for $g=k$, I thought about being a semi-sphere but I have no idea.